# Object created in Spring

Tags: spring, object

I would like to know, whether this is a valid practice to use "`new`" in spring to create a `Object`?
You can either use `xml->bean` to create a object using xml file or use annotations to create a object.

This question arises when I am working on a project and where I want to create a object of a property class(which contains properties and `setter/getter` method of those properties).

I am able to create a object using new and its working fine but if spring has capability to create and manage object lifecycle then which way I need to go create a object and why?

Answer (score 0):

I think the confusion may arise because of the (over)usage of spring as DI mechanism. Spring is a framework providing many services. Bean or dependency injection is just on of those.

I would say that for POJOs which have just setter and getters without much logic in them you can safely create objects using new keyword. For example, in case of value objects and data classes which do not have much configuration or life cycle events to worry about, go ahead and crate those using new keyword. If you repetitively create these objects and have fields which are not changing often, then I would use spring because it will lessen some of the repetitive code and object creation can be considered externalized or separated from your object usage.

Classes instantiated using spring bean definition xml/annotations are basically 'Spring-Managed' beans which mostly means that their life cycle, scope, etc are managed by spring. Spring manages objects which are beans, which may have some life cycle methods and APIs. These beans are dependencies for the classes in which the are set. The parent objects call some API of these dependencies to fulfil some business cases.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The Dependency Injection concept in spring is more useful when we need to construct an object that depends upon many objects, because it saves you time and effort for constructing as well as instantiating dependent objects.

In your case , Since it's a POJO class with only setters and getters , I think it is absolutely safe to instantiate it using a new keyword.